# How to add Text with Radio Button/CheckBox using iText7?

Tags: c#, .net-core, itext7

I am able to add Radio buttons and checkboxs in PDF using this library but I cannot see any Text with it.

Here is my Code:

```
_values = ["One","Two"];
    foreach (var value in _values)
                            {
                                var checkBoxField = PdfFormField.CreateCheckBox(drawContext.GetDocument(),
                                    new Rectangle(x,y,width,height), _fieldName + count++, value);
                                form.AddField(checkBoxField);
                                count++;
                                x += width;
                                if (count > 3)
                                {
                                    count = 1;
                                    x = box.GetX();
                                    y += height;
                                }
                            }
```

[image]
But I see the Checbox button but not the Text beside it.
If this is not possible how can I add a label besides it.

Thanks

Comment: Simply arrange text net to the radio buttons or check boxes; the PDF standard does not couple these form elements with a label.

Comment: @mkl ok i guess I am bound to that then thank you